# Replacing v-data-table with v-virtual-scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

my task would be to replace my v-data-table with v-virtual-scroll, i cant seem to find out the correct syntax for the virtual-scroller, could you help me out please? I want to display just like it was ,but now with the virtual scroller .

```
  <div v-if="import_table.display">
           <v-data-table
                v-if="!hide_table"
                :headers="import_table.headers"
                :items="import_table.data"
                hide-default-footer
                :items-per-page="-1"
                dense
              > 

       <!--   <v-virtual-scroll
            :headers="import_table.headers"
            :items="import_table.data"
            v-if="!hide_table"                        ---->**thats how i replaced** 
            :item-height="50"
            height="300"
          >  -->


            <template v-slot:item="{ item, index }">
              <tr>
              <td>
            **CODE**
              </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>     <!-- </v-virtual-scroll> -->
```

probably it has to do with the tr td tags, i tried to replace them with v-item-content, action  but nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-virtual-scroll/#props) `v-virtual-scroll` does not have slot named `item`. It has only one default slot. Also it does not have `headers` prop.

If you want to render items inside your `v-virtual-scroll` you should use this syntax:

```html
<v-virtual-scroll :items="items"
                  item-height="50">
  <template v-slot="{ item, index }">
    <!-- Your item content here -->
  </template>
</v-virtual-scroll>
```

Also, right now (Vuetify 2.3.10) there is no way to set tag for the virtual scroll. So using `tr` and `td` inside it is not a valid HTML. I would suggest to display it as a custom table.